# Data is not being inserted by the following query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "INSERT INTO personal_details ( first_name, last_name,password, email_id, password,
                     gender,blood_group,mobile_number,AgeGroupIndex )
          VALUES ( '$fname','$lname', '$password', '$email', '$gender','$blood_group',
                     '$mobile','$birthdate','$AgeGroup' )";
mysql_query($query);
```

The data is not being inserted into it. Can anyone troubleshoot?

Comment: Switch to "mysqli_" and use parameters.

Comment: With the help of http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php you can get the actual error, which will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: you must have something wrong in your query, do you have two fields in your database table `personal_details` named `password`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're duplicating "password", after "email".
Also, "birthdate" is wrong

```
$query = "INSERT INTO personal_details 
(first_name,last_name,password,email_id,gender,blood_group,mobile_number,AgeGroupIndex ) VALUES ( '$fname','$lname','$password','$email','$gender','$blood_group','$mobile','$AgeGroup' )";
mysql_query($query);
```

UPDATE

As **Hek mat** mentions in the comments, you should use prepared statements

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: what about to use `prepared statements?`.this is not solution.You can comment it.

Comment: check the number of parameters they don't match. Edit your answer.

Comment: @Hekmat this is not for arguing he should use `prepared statements`.

Comment: @brunofitas but you may know about it.and about `sql injection`

Comment: Hek mat is right... he should use prepared statement.. but is not using them. @PeterDarmis Thanks for the warning ;-)

Comment: @Hekmat You're totally right. I wouldn't use this sort of queries... I'm gonna update the answer with it.